# Java - Swing - painting (adding another shapes on a JPanel)

Tags: java, swing, paint

class that makes a JFrame, adds a JPanel on it and draws a rectangle on the JPanel

```
class Frame {
JFrame frame;
myPanel panel;

void draw() {
    frame = new JFrame ("qwertz");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(300,200);

    panel = new myPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    frame.add(panel);

    myPanel.a = 50;
    myPanel.b = 30;
}
void add() {
    //
}}
```

second class is the JPanel that the first class uses

```
class myPanel extends JPanel {
static int a;
static int b;
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(a,a,b,b);
}}
```

---

what is the easiest way to add another rectangle on the panel ?
(I would like the code that adds it to be in the add() method in the first class, if its possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to call a method "add".  Every Swing component has an add method.

Create a GUI model class that holds as many rectangles as you want to define.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RectangleModel {

    private List<Rectangle> rectangles;

    public RectangleModel() {
        this.rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    }

    public void addRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.rectangles.add(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
    }

    public void addRectangle(Rectangle rectangle) {
        this.rectangles.add(rectangle);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
            g.drawRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width,
                    rectangle.height);
        }
    }

}
```

Modify your JPanel so it looks like this:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private RectangleModel model;

    public MyPanel(RectangleModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        model.draw(g);
    }}
}
```

Now, all your main class has to do is:

- Execute `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to put all of your GUI components on the Event Dispatch thread (EDT).
- Create your GUI model.
- Create your GUI frame class and panel class.
- Add Rectangles to your GUI model.
- Pack the JFrame.